# executing SQL stored procedure in R

Tags: sql, r

Im trying to execute a stored procedure and get the output from SQL in R, the output is around 111,267 rows with 15 columns.

When using this script:

```
library(RODBC)
connecttodb = function()
{  
connline = paste0("driver={SQL Server};server=foo;database=;Trusted_Connection=yes")    
conn = odbcDriverConnect(connline)  
return(conn)    
}

Query <- paste0("exec reports..CRA_v9")
conn <- connecttodb()
Output <- sqlQuery(conn, Query,stringAsFactors=FALSE) 
odbcClose(conn)
```

I instead get:

```
                                                               V1
1: [RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'exec reports..CRA_v9'
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, i had to 'set nocount on' in the first line of my stored procedure